# Why am I receiving a "thread exiting with uncaught exception” in Android?

Tags: android

The thing I'm trying to implement is a `OnClick` for my `ListView` so when I click in my `ListView` in `tab1`, I want to switch tabs to `tab2` and then I want to save the clicked `ListView` row to be displayed in same `ListView` in `tab2` but with more information. But I'm getting this error.

Why am I getting this error, and how can I display the chosen row in `tab1` to `tab2`?

```
public class Tab1 extends TabActivity {

    WifiManager wifiManager;
    WifiScanReceiver wifiReciever;
    String ssid;
    int channel;
    int level;
    ArrayAdapter adapter;
    ListView list;
    ArrayList<String> wifis;
    WifiInfo wifiInfo;
    TabHost tabHost = null;

    // TabSpec Names
    private static final String TAB1 = "Tab1";
    private static final String TAB2 = "Tab2";
    private static final String TAB3 = "Tab3";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tab1);

        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.text);
        wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        wifiReciever = new WifiScanReceiver();
        wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();

        wifis = new ArrayList<String>(); //initialize wifis
        wifis.add("loading...");
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, wifis);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);

        wifiManager.startScan(); //make sure this is the last call
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
                v.findViewById(R.id.text);
                switchTab(1);
            }
        }); };

    public void switchTabs(int tab) {
        tabHost.setCurrentTab(tab);
    }

    public void switchTab(int tab) {
        tabHost.setCurrentTab(tab);
    }

    protected void onPause() {
        unregisterReceiver(wifiReciever);
        super.onPause();
    }

    public static int convertFrequencyToChannel(int freq) {
        if (freq >= 2412 && freq <= 2484) {
            return (freq - 2412) / 5 + 1;
        } else if (freq >= 5170 && freq <= 5825) {
            return (freq - 5170) / 5 + 34;
        } else {
            return -1;
        }
    }

    protected void onResume() {
        registerReceiver(wifiReciever, new IntentFilter(
                WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));
        super.onResume();
    }


    class WifiScanReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        @SuppressLint("UseValueOf")
        public void onReceive(Context c, Intent intent) {
            List<ScanResult> wifiScanList = wifiManager.getScanResults();
            wifis.clear(); //add this
            for (int i = 0; i < wifiScanList.size(); i++) {
                ssid = wifiScanList.get(i).SSID; //Get the SSID
                level = wifiScanList.get(i).level;
                channel = wifiScanList.get(i).frequency;

                //use add here:
                wifis.add(ssid + " " + level + " dBm "); //append to the other data
                wifis.toString();
            }

            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); //add this
            wifiManager.startScan(); //start a new scan to update values faster

        }
    }

}
```

Error messages

```
05-20 10:40:42.710    4694-4694/com.example.isac.tabtry W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41477930)
05-20 10:40:42.718    4694-4694/com.example.isac.tabtry E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NullPointerException

       at com.example.isac.tabtry.Tab1.switchTab(Tab1.java:73)
        at com.example.isac.tabtry.Tab1$1.onItemClick(Tab1.java:64)
        at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:301)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1508)
        at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3293)
        at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:4554)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5365)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: ive read the article and i understand what he is saying, thanks. But where is the variable with no pointer in my code?

Comment: Post full stack trace of exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not initializing the `tabHost` object in your whole code, as this object is not initialized your code :

```
 public void switchTab(int tab) {
        tabHost.setCurrentTab(tab); // Throwing exception here
    }
```

`tabHost` = `null` here. Set it first.

Comment: i now initialized tabHost with null now but error is still there

Comment: I have not suggested you to set it to null. Initialize it to some value like : tabHost = new TabHost(this); something like this. It should not be 'null' otherwise it will throw NPE.

Comment: ,this works thanks, but now i cant change currenttab :S

Comment: I think you are using TabHost for first time search google for some tutorials, here one i found : http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-tablayout-example/

Comment: thanks man, ive read it now. But in my onclick i have tabHost.setCurrentTab(1); but when i click it doesnt change.